# Javascript function onload never called

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I wish to get a json file with a get request from a webservice, and I have a "cross origin request", so I check "withCredentials", and then I use the onload function to display the content of the json on the console.

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    console.log("withCredentials is true");

    xhr.onload = function() {
      console.log('ok');
      if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
        data.forEach(card => {
          console.log(card.nameEnglish1);
        })
      } else {
        console.log('error');
      }
    };

    xhr.onerror = function() {
      console.log('There was an error!');
    };

  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', 'http://192.168.42.176:8080/batch-recup-mtg-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mtg/cards/search?setCode=AKH');
if (!xhr) {
  throw new Error('CORS not supported');
}
```

But nothing happen, my onload function is never called, and I don't have any error. I'm sure that the webservice is working because I tried it in my browser. Do you have any idea why the onload function is never called?

EDIT : `console.log("withCredentials is true");` is displayed, but `console.log('ok');` isn't

Comment: So is request being made in dev tools network? Not much debugging detail provided here

Comment: Are you sure `"withCredentials" in xhr` is true?

Comment: `"withCredentials"` is true, because I placed a console.log after this statement to check if it was true, and the console log is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

```
xhr.send();
```

```js
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    console.log("withCredentials is true");

    xhr.onload = function() {
      console.log('ok');
      if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
        data.forEach(card => {
          console.log(card.nameEnglish1);
        })
      } else {
        console.log('error');
      }
    };

    xhr.onerror = function() {
      console.log('There was an error!');
    };

    // added send call here:
    xhr.send();

  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', 'http://google.com/');
if (!xhr) {
  throw new Error('CORS not supported');
}
```

Comment: `xhr.send()` isn't needed for `XDomainRequest`?