# Reponse is not getting printed on console

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
console.log("i am inside news");

let source_key = '843d077d0e284d9095222b63b55d0c94';
let source = 'the-times-of-india';
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?sources=the-times-of-india&apiKey=843d077d0e284d9095222b63b55d0c94', true);
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        let json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
         console.log(json)
      }
      else{
          console.log("Some error occured")
      }
     
  }
```

The above code is not printing the response on the console .Trying to console.log json but output on console.

Comment: You need to invoke [`xhr.send()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) to start the actual request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript function onload never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599552/javascript-function-onload-never-called)

Answer (score 2):

In the example here for [XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onload), you have to call `xhr.send()`

```js
console.log("i am inside news");

let source_key = '843d077d0e284d9095222b63b55d0c94';
let source = 'the-times-of-india';

// create the request
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// initialize the request
xhr.open('GET', 'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?sources=the-times-of-india&apiKey=843d077d0e284d9095222b63b55d0c94', true);
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (this.status === 200) {
    let json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(json)
  } else {
    console.log("Some error occured")
  }

}
// send the request
xhr.send()
```

Comment: Stil not getting the reponse

Comment: Check the error message that comes back from the server.